# PHP file_get_contens error with symbols

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST["submitmail"])){
        if(strlen($_POST["mail"]) >= 5){
            $api = file_get_contents("http://www.url.com/api/email/".$_POST["mail"]);

            if($api == "good"){
                echo "<script>alert('welcome);</script>";    
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('bye');</script>";
        }
    }
```

And om the "url.com" api:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["email"])){
    if(strlen($_GET["email"]) >= 5){

        echo "good";

    }
}
```

The problem is that every time I write a dot (".") or a @, it gives me this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://...@wd): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/toAPI/index.php on line 5
```

Trying to change every dot to ** and @ to *** doesn't work either. since it gives the very same problem. I use htaccess, and the file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteRule ^email/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?email=$1
RewriteRule ^email/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?email=$1
```

Comment: what does your `$_POST['mail']` contains?

Comment: An emailadress, mabe hello@hello.com and my code gives me errors at @ and .

Comment: And the error says that you have entered wrong path so that's why you are not getting the file..?

Comment: but how could I've done that?

Comment: What are you trying to do at line?? `file_get_conetents` ??

Answer (score 1):

Your htaccess does not match any valid email, that's why you get `404` error - `page not found`. First print out your URL and check if you can access this url.

Regex for email ([source](http://emailregex.com/)):

```
/^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/iD
```

Comment: That's a very crazy way to validate your email using this RFC 5322 grammar..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai You always can use something like `/^\w+@\w+\.\w{3}/` if you prefer miss some custom format emails (like `jj_99-g@acd.co.uk`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** 
Your Regex is only looking for `A-Z,a-z,0-9` and that is not a valid Regex for checking an Email.

**Solution :**
Instead validate your email using `filter_var` in PHP as :

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "Valid email address.";
} else {
  echo "Invalid email address.";
}
```